# Is equal sign passing a reference or object copy?

Tags: c#, string, object, reference

When I have this code:

```
class A 
{
    public int X = 0;
 ...
}

public void Function()
{
    // here I create a new instance of class
    A a = new A();
    a.X = 10;
    // here I create a pointer to null
    A b = null;
    // here I assign a to b
    b = a;
    b.X = 20;
}
```

did I pass the reference to instance of class A now? or I cloned the instance of A to new instance and created a reference to it in b?

is changing X in b also changing X in a? Why? If not, what is a proper way to create a copy of a and insert that to b?

Why the same with strings would always create a copy? Is equal operator overridden in strings?

```
string a = "hello";
string b = a;
b = "world";
// "hello world"
Console.WriteLine( a + " " + b );
```

Comment: These are not pointers. C# uses references.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C# uses references not pointers. Classes are [*`reference types`*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx).

On your example,  `b` has the same reference with `a`. They referencing the same location on memory.

> changing X in b also changing X in a? Why?

Yes, because they reference to the same objects and changing one reference will affect the other one.

```
string a = "hello";
string b = a;
b = "world";
// "hello world"
Console.WriteLine( a + " " + b );
```

Strings are *reference types* also. But they are also [`immutable type`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). Which means you can't change them. Even if you think you change them, you actually create new strings object.

1. line you create an object contains `"hello"` with a reference called `a`.
2. line you create a new reference called `b` referencing to the same object. (`"hello"`)
3. line you assign your `b` reference new object called `"world"`. Your b referance is not referencing `"hello"` object anymore.

Comment: It's a bit confusing to say that C# does not use pointers and then go on to say that they are "pointing" to the same memory location!!

Comment: For others: C# does not use "pointer", it use "reference". But "reference" is conceptually "type-safe pointer". Both references and pointers are point to a location in memory, but the reference has clarifies what type of data this location is. `Pointer says: this is a location.` `Reference says: this is a location of string.`

Answer (score 4):

> did I pass the pointer to instance of class A now? or I cloned the
>   instance of A to new instance and created a pointer to it in b?

**`b` is holding the same reference as `a`**, both of them pointing to the same location.

> changing X in b also changing X in a? Why?

Because both of them are pointing to the same reference.

> what is a proper way to create a copy of a and insert that to b?

Implement [IClonable interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx)

> Supports cloning, which creates a new instance of a class with the
>   same value as an existing instance

**EDIT**

Since you edited the question with string, although strings are reference types but they are [**immutable**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) as well

[string (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/362314fe.aspx)

> Strings are immutable--the contents of a string object cannot be
>   changed after the object is created, although the syntax makes it
>   appear as if you can do this.

Answer (score 1):

Object b is pointing to the object a, you have to do the deep clone to make a copy using `IClonable`  Interface.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign, you pass a copy of the return value of the assigned expression.

- For **value types**, this is the value you usually get to see when you use them (like the numerical value of an integer).
- For **reference types**, the actual value is something like an address pointing to the referenced object (but, what it *really* is, is an implementation detail). So, even though you pass a copy of that address, that copy points to the same object.